# How to resolve WindowsAzure.Mobile references?

Tags: azure

I’m trying this example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users.  The example says to add the Using statement below to restrict permissions to authenticated users:  using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security.  It’s not resolving though and I get all kinds of "unable to resolve dependency" errors.

I've tried adding references, installing Nuget add-ons with anything Azure related (e.g. SDK), but it just generates other errors.  Does anyone know the magic combination for making this thing resolve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: I didn't need the using statement after all.  I was using the preview portal to get my sample code and the documentation to perform the task is different depending on if you got your sample code from the preview portal or the "standard" Azure portal.  As I was using the preview portal I needed to use this documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users-preview/

Thanks to: Matthew Henderson